# How to Routes URL Dynamic with Switch Case?

Tags: php

I Have some code :

```
<?php
switch (REQUESTED_URL) {
    case '/home' :
        require __DIR__ . '/views/Home.php';
        break;
      case '' :
        require __DIR__ . '/views/Home.php';
        break; 
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo "Internal Server Error (Routes URL Not Found)";
        exit();
        break;
}
?>
```

How to use switch case function for dynamic url ? ex : /home/$1

Comment: Put more details about problem and your code and what you want?

Comment: If you are making a routing system, you should not use query parameters and instead make it more SEO friendly with something like `home/123`. At the backend, you know it's an ID.

Comment: I haven't started it yet, I don't know how to implement it, can it be a dynamic url routing use switch case function?

Comment: Your question is Unclear because there is no context.  We don't get any sample input values and no desired result.  Please complete your question so that you can receive quality/accurate support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `switch` compares equality of the specified string to a list of values, just as `if($string == $excepted_value) {}` ([see documentation for the `switch` control structure](https://php.net/switch)). It doesn't check whether a string matches a regex expression, so you can't check for a dynamic URL inside a `switch` structure.

Instead, to support dynamic URLs (i.e. with query parameters), try to use inbuilt features of PHP, for example `$_GET` for URL query parameters, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for the request URI, and regex expressions to extract specific parts of that URI.